# Action not being called on page load

Tags: ruby, voltrb

In my ruby Volt project, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeBinding Error: #<NoMethodError: 'undefined method `name' for nil'>
```

I know that it is coming from trying to access the name attribute on the model while it is nil. My routes file is the following:

```
client '/practices/new', component: 'admin', controller: 'offices', action: 'new'
```

The method 'new' assigns the model to a buffer but it is not being called on the page load. Anyone know why?

Comment: The new method in my controller has one line and is as follows: 'self.model = store._offices.buffer'

Comment: We need to see your `new` code to help, and the exception backtrace would also be useful.

Comment: And where do you call "name" at all? on what object? because that is nil, and you have not told us anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're referring to `{{ name }}` rather than `{{ _name }}` in your view. Try the underscore notation or define an `Offices` model with a `name` field. The docs on that are [here](http://docs.voltframework.com/en/docs/models.html).

I get the `AttributeBinding` error if I don't use the underscore notation on an attribute that's not defined on a model.